# How to update post meta single value in multi dimensional array?

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically, I'm creating a  custom polls system for the WooCommerce product page in which the user will select the radio option and click on a submit button to cast vote.

Each poll item could have multiple items and each item has 3 fields of data. All data save in a meta value for a post.

How I code PHP function for ajax action handeler to update single value in multi dimensional post meta array.
in my code its not update just save the new valu to all field instead of the field I voted.

```
$polls = get_post_meta($post_id,'polls',true);
```

Dump data of `$polls`

```
array(3) {
  [0] => array(3) {
    ["title"] => string(15) "This is Title 1" 
    ["color_code"] => string(7) " "40"
  } [2] => array(3) {
    ["title"] => string(15) "This is Title 2"
    ["color_code"] => string(7) "#8224e3" 
    ["vote_number"] => string(2) "30"
  } [3] => array(3) {
    ["title"] => string(15) "This is Title 3" 
    ["color_code"] => string(7) "#eeee22" 
    ["vote_number"] => string(2)"50"
  }
}
```

Fornt End

[image]

Backend
[image]
Poll extract from to Show in a form  for casting vote

```
<form id="poll_form" method="post" action="">
<input id="post_id_number" type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $post_id;?>">
    <ul>
    <?php 
    $title_array_data =  explode(',', $title_array);
    $color_array_data =  explode(',', $color_array);
    $vote_array_data =  explode(',', $vote_array);

    foreach ($title_array_data as $key => $value) { ?>
      <li>
          <input id="poll-vote-<?php echo $key;?>" name="polls[<?php echo $key;?>][vote_number]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $vote_array_data[$key];?>" class="poll-item"/>
          <input id="poll-item-<?php echo $key;?>" name="polls[<?php echo $key;?>][radio]" type="radio" value="1" class="poll-item"/>
          <label id="pollitemlabel" for="poll-item-<?php echo $key;?>" style="color:<?php echo $color_array_data[$key] ;?>"><?php echo $value;?> </label>
      </li>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>
    <li class="submitbutton"><input type="submit" class="submit-vote" value="Vote"></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

This is how the HTML form markup looks like

```
    <form id="thebomb_poll_form" method="post" action="">
    <input id="post_id_number" type="hidden" name="post_id" value="10255" />
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input id="poll-vote-0" name="polls[0][vote_number]" type="hidden" value="40" class="poll-item" />
            <input id="poll-item-0" name="polls[0][radio]" type="radio" value="1" class="poll-item" />
            <label id="pollitemlabel" for="poll-item-0" style="color: #81d742;">This is Title 1 </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input id="poll-vote-1" name="polls[1][vote_number]" type="hidden" value="30" class="poll-item" />
            <input id="poll-item-1" name="polls[1][radio]" type="radio" value="1" class="poll-item" />
            <label id="pollitemlabel" for="poll-item-1" style="color: #8224e3;">This is Title 2 </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input id="poll-vote-2" name="polls[2][vote_number]" type="hidden" value="50" class="poll-item" />
            <input id="poll-item-2" name="polls[2][radio]" type="radio" value="1" class="poll-item" />
            <label id="pollitemlabel" for="poll-item-2" style="color: #eeee22;">This is Title 3 </label>
        </li>
        <li class="submitbutton"><input type="submit" class="submit-vote" value="Vote" style="display: inline-block;" /></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

PHP function for ajax action handeler

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_cast_vote', 'vote_cast_ajax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_cast_vote', 'vote_cast_ajax' );

function vote_cast_ajax(){

    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    
    //getting meta value
    $polls = get_post_meta($post_id,'polls',true);
    
    $vote_data_array = array_column($polls, 'vote_number');
    $vote_array = implode(',', $vote_data_array);//used in shortcode    
    
    if (is_array($polls)) {
        // polls is the array, key is numeric index, vote is subarray
        foreach ($polls as $key => $vote) {
            $old_vote = $pols[$key]['vote_number'] ;
            $newvote += (int)$old_vote + 1 ;
            
            $vote[$key]['vote_number'] = $newvote;                               
        }
        update_post_meta($post_id,'polls',$vote);
    }
    

    wp_send_json_success( sprintf(
        __( 'Your vote has been cast successfully!.', 'ng-vote' )
    ) );
}
```

Jquery code for ajax request handling

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".submitbutton .submit-vote").click(function (e) {
        // Prevent them from actually visiting the URL when clicking.
        e.preventDefault();

        // Add a little 'waiting' thingie to the cursor.
        $(document.body).css({ cursor: "wait" });
        var serialized = $("#thebomb_poll_form").serialize();
        // Start ajaxin'!
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ThebombAjax.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action: "cast_vote", //calls TBAjax
                post_id: $("#post_id_number").val(),
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                // Add an alert with our success message.
                alert(response.data);

                // Change the cursor back to normal.
                $(document.body).css({ cursor: "default" });
            },
        }).fail(function (response) {
            // This stuff only happens if things fail miserably.
            $(document.body).css({ cursor: "default" });
            if (window.console && window.console.log) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code. you have to push "$newvote" to "$polls[$key]['vote_number']"

```
// polls is the array, key is numeric index, vote is subarray
foreach ($polls as $key => $vote) {
    $old_vote = $vote['vote_number'] ;
    $newvote += (int)$old_vote + 1 ;
    
    $polls[$key]['vote_number'] = $newvote;                               
}
update_post_meta($post_id,'polls',$polls);
```

Comment: increasing in every field for example 1 becomes 2   and 2 becomes 3  so increase value in every field. we should have to pass the key value and update depending on that key so it will not increased all value